# get document checksum

Tags: list, document-library, document

For development I want to retrieve or display a list of all my files in my document center. Now I want to be able to validate the document with a `checksum`. 
I am making a service that connects to SP and downloads the files, and I want to validate the download with the checksum.

Is it possible to retrieve and display a checksum of a document in the document list? What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be a bit complicated.

- First of all you will have to  put checksums somehow on the documents: this means you will need to decide which documents this are doc or docx as it will be a different work to perform. Checksums are stored in the metadata of the document (docx is a zip).
- Secondly you will have to retrieve the checksum
- And third to do all this you will have to write some code or find some examples which explain how to calculate the checksums.

Basically of course this is possible, but i think it will take some effort to implement and get this working.

I hope this info was a bit useful. Although i dont give you exact information about it as i never came across such a demand.

Comment: so there is no default call 'getChecksum()' or something like that?
Eventually I want to access the list via the webservice and get back something like this https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files?hl=en including the md5checksum.

Comment: 4 years later and I am hoping for the same thing as @Bokw was -- curious if there was a checksum found.  SharePoint has to do this internally in some way, shape, or form.  Unless it creates a version for every check in, regardless if the file was the same or not.  (I hope not)  I hope it would only create a new revision if the checksums (or metadata items) are different.  The big hope being the checksum is available, since its more robust